# How to add a progress bar to Vuetify Snackbar?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I look to an elegant way to add a progress bar to the Snackbar component of Vuetify. The bar must be sync with the timeout prop. I used a setInterval but It's maybe better to apply style directly on the component?

```html
<template>
  <v-snackbar :value="true" :timeout="timeout" light>
    <span>Text to display</span>
    <v-progress-linear absolute bottom :value="progressValue" />
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SnackBarProgress',
  props: {
    timeout: {
      type: Number,
      default: 5000
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    progressValue: 0,
    steps: 1,
    interval: null
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.startProgress();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  methods: {
    startProgress() {
      if (this.timeout < 1) {
        return;
      }

      clearInterval(this.interval);

      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.steps === this.timeout) {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          return;
        }

        this.steps = this.steps + 100;
        this.progressValue = Math.round((this.steps / this.timeout) * 100);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally how I would do it is set a `setTimeout` that evaluates the current status of the timer, and bind that to the progress bar.

First, let's create a component that accepts a [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) that will relate to showing the snack bar. To do this we need to have a `value` prop. We will also create a prop for the timeout in milliseconds with a default value of 5 seconds.

```js
props: {
    value: {
      default: false,
    },
    timeout: {
      default: 5 * 1000,
    },
}
```

Next, we will create a variable to track our current time

```js
data() {
  return {
    currentTime: 0,
  };
},
```

Now we will create our method to increment the progress bar 10 times a second. If the current time is greater than the timeout then we need to update the v-model to hide the snackbar

```js
methods: {
 syncPbar() {
   //Create a timeout every 100 miliseconds
   setTimeout(() => {
     //Increment the time counter by 100
     this.currentTime += 100;

     //If our current time is larger than the timeout
     if (this.timeout <= this.currentTime) {

       //Wait 500 miliseconds for the dom to catch up, then reset the snackbar
       setTimeout(() => {            
         this.$emit("input", false); //Update the v-model to false
         this.currentTime = 0; // reset the current time
       }, 500);
     } else {
       //Recursivly update the progress bar
       this.syncPbar();
     }
   }, 100);
 }
}
```

Then we need to monitor the value (incoming from the v-model) and if it is true then begin the countdown.

```js
watch: {
  value(v) {
    if (v) this.syncPbar();
  }
}
```

Finally, we will create our template. Since `v-progress-linear` expects the value to be 0-100 we need to calculate the percentage of time that has elapsed. The easiest way to do this is to divide `currentTime` and the `timeout` and multiply it by 100. However this could give us a float, so we need to force it to be an integer by using `Math.floor()` so we round down to the nearest percentage point. We also need to create a [`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) to host our snack bar's text.

```html
<template>
  <v-snackbar :value="value" light>
    <span>
      <slot></slot>
    </span>

    <v-progress-linear
      absolute
      bottom
      :value="Math.floor(100 * (currentTime / timeout))"
    />
  </v-snackbar>
</template>
```

Now that we have our component created we can use it in our parent we just need to specify a timeout and a v-model.

```html
<mySnack 
    v-model="showSnack"
    :timeout="5 * 1000"
    > 
      Snackbar text 
</mySnack>
```

To see a full working example please see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67072195-5r0yt?file=/src/components/MySnack.vue) I created.